# Getting the output POST Request using C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a hard time getting the Output for a Webhook on a specific part of JSON Request.

You can see it right here:

[image: You can see it right here]

I'm using Ngrok for getting the requests. I also created a class which I will call for parsing or getting the JSON file but it failed:

```
public class FormData
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

This is the endpoint being posted to:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using MultipartParser;
using MultipartParser.Data;
using WebApplication3.Objects;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public string Post(string mode, string challenge, FormData data)
        {
            string test = data.Data;
            //JToken jtoken = JSONData.GetValue("active");
            //string val = jtoken.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(test);

            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What I am getting in this code is a 204 No Content.

Comment: Okay so This is a webhook. The JSON that you saw earlier is the response from the 3rd Party application. My goal is to get the "resource_url" part on that JSON response. Thanks!

Comment: The screenshot is the response that I was getting from the webhook response. It is an actual data coming from the other app. The endpoint, callback url was a ngrok forwarding to a localhost.

Comment: I'm using a .NET Framework and this is a Web API.

Comment: Have you resolved 500 error? Not exactly getting the actual question

Comment: Ah yes, ignore that on the picture. What I am really getting is 204 No Content I always getting null if I add a breakpoint.

Comment: means "data.Data" is always NULL. right? 
OR data itself is NULL?

Comment: The Data itself is null. I don't know if I'm writing the right codes for getting the output response

Answer (score 0):

Your FormData class is wrong which results Null when request received in your api.

Paste your json in below link which will give you the proper class you have to use.
http://json2csharp.com

Comment: Okay just finished trying this one. Still returning No Content

[HttpPost]
        public string Post(RootObject url)
        {
            string test = url.resource_url;
            //JToken jtoken = JSONData.GetValue("active");
            //string val = jtoken.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(test);

            return test;
        }

Comment: Is it your RootObject is bind correctly in controller. I mean not NULL

Comment: Still NULL I made it as a parameter already  public string Post(RootObject url)

Comment: It is being passed on my callback_url but when I continue the breakpoints that I set it returns NULL